# HttpGet method not called with attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

The `GetItems` method is working fine but `GetItem` with the attribute "id" is not. I get all items returned when I send the GET request, meaning `GetItems()` is called instead. What am I missing?

```
// GET request: https://localhost:xxxxx/api/Items
// Working
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Item>>> GetItems()
{
    return await _context.items.ToListAsync();
}

// GET request: https://localhost:xxxxx/api/Items/2
// Not running
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Item>> GetItem(long id)
{
   var item = await _context.items.FindAsync(id);

    if (item == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return item;
}
```

I would like to filter items with name, but this has the same problem as GetItem(long id) above, all items are returned.

```
GET request: https://localhost:xxxxx/api/Items?name=aaa 
    
// Not running
[HttpGet("{name}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Item>>> GetItems(string name)
{
    var item = await _context.items.Where(x => x.Name == name).ToListAsync();

    if (item == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return item;
}

[HttpPost]
   public async Task<ActionResult<TodoItem>> PostTodoItem(TodoItem todoItem)
        {
            _context.TodoItems.Add(todoItem);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetTodoItemById), new { id = todoItem.Id }, todoItem);
        }
```

Response example:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "aaa",
    "isRegistered": true
}
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "aaa",
    "isRegistered": false
}
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "bbb",
    "isRegistered": false
}
```

Configure method in Startup.cs:

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

        }
```

Comment: Could you please share your code which call this endapoints? and also your routing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `Action` to your `Route`,like this:`[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]`,below is a work demo:

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class ItemsController : ControllerBase
{
   //...

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Item>>> GetItems()
    {
        return await _context.Items.ToListAsync();
    }


    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Item>> GetItemById(int id)
    {
       
        var item = await _context.Items.FindAsync(id);

        if (item == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return item;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Item>>> GetItemByName(string name)
    {
        var item = await _context.Items.Where(x => x.Name == name).ToListAsync();

        if (item == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return item;
    }
}
```

GET request:

1:`https://localhost:xxxxx/api/Items/getitems`

Result:
[image]

2:`https://localhost:xxxxx/api/Items/GetItemById?id=xx`

Result:
[image]

3:`https://localhost:xxxxx/api/Items/GetItemByName?name=xx`

Result:
[image]

Post Request:

`https://localhost:xxxxx/api/Items/todoitem`

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, with this solution I don't get all items any more with GetItemById and GetItemByName, but since data is cleared up each time I debug, I only get "404 not found". Post-method does not work with this solution returning "HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid". I have added my POST-method code.

Comment: The only method working is GetItems returning no data with code 200 OK.

Comment: What kind of data are you clearing? Why does it cause a 404 error after clearing the data? Normally, this will not affect routing. Your post method will return 400 because you did not pass the correct parameter type. I updated my answer and you can see that the post method works normally.

Comment: All the items I create get removed from the server on a new debugging. I am following the instruction in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio  
Anyhow, it is working now with your solution, after fixing the POST method - the URL was not including the action. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

check your startup that has this lines:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
```

also check this for first item:

```
 [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
```

also you can do this:

```
GET request: https://localhost:xxxxx/api/GetItems?name=aaa 
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Item>>> GetItems(string name)
{
var item = await _context.items.Where(x => x.Name == name).ToListAsync();

if (item == null)
{
    return NotFound();
}

return item;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Decorate your controller with the **route** attribute as shown below:

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/Items")]
    public class ItemsController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Item>>> GetItems()
        {
            return await _context.items.ToListAsync();
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Item>> GetItem(long id)
        {
            var item = await _context.items.FindAsync(id);

            if (item == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return item;
        }
    }
```

Then you should be able to get filtered list by using the request parameter such as `https://localhost:xxxxx/api/Items/2`

Comment: Thank you for your help. The route was already as you described. When I send https://localhost:xxxxx/api/Items/2, I get a 405 error (Method not allowed).